# Handling errors

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

What's great about golfing is not having to deal with errors. Except this time you won't get off so lightly! I need to do some arithmetic with certain limitations, and I wan't to know what goes wrong if anything.

## Challenge

Given a list of signed integer values `[n1..n11]`, give the following result *or* the first error that occurred.

```
(((((((((n1+n2)-n3)^n4)/n5)*n6)+n7)-n8)^n9)/n10)*n11
```

The same in reverse polish notation:

```
n1 n2 + n3 - n4 ^ n5 / n6 * n7 + n8 - n9 ^ n10 / n11 *
```

The operators have the following limitations:

- `0^0` → error `0^0 is undefined`
- `0^a` when `a<0` → error `Negative exponent`
- `a/0` → error `Division by zero`
- `a/b` when `mod a b != 0` → error `Uneven division`
- for any operator: `result < 0` → error `Integer underflow`
- for any operator: `result > 99` → error `Integer overflow`
- for any operator: either input value or result == 13 → error `13 is bad luck!`

Errors occur left to right, so `13/0` = error `13 is bad luck!`.

### Scoring

The shortest code in bytes wins. To encourage readability string literals used for errors won't count towards the score.

The output format isn't strict but all seven errors plus a correct value must be distinguishable. Your program/function must retain control flow until the end, so e.g. any exceptions must be caught.

Standard loopholes are disallowed.

## Examples

```
[6,7,14,2,0,1,2,3,4,0,6]   → error `13 is bad luck!`
[6,6,14,2,0,1,2,3,4,0,6]   → error `Integer underflow`
[6,6,12,0,0,1,2,3,4,0,6]   → error `0^0 is undefined`
[6,6,12,2,0,1,2,3,4,0,6]   → error `Division by zero`
[6,6,10,6,12,1,2,3,4,0,6]  → error `Uneven division`
[6,6,10,6,8,17,2,13,4,0,6] → error `Integer overflow`
[6,6,10,6,8,7,99,13,4,0,6] → error `Integer overflow`
[6,6,10,6,8,7,9,99,4,0,6]  → error `Integer underflow`
[6,6,10,6,8,7,9,55,-2,0,0] → error `Negative exponent`
[6,6,10,6,8,7,9,56,2,0,8]  → error `Division by zero`
[6,6,10,6,8,7,9,56,2,9,12] → error `Integer overflow`
[6,6,10,6,8,7,9,56,2,9,11] → 99
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Haskell, <s>190</s> <s>186</s> 185 bytes

311 bytes total, 185 bytes without the string literals.

```
e=Left
0#0=e"0^0 is undefined"
b#_|b<0=e"Negative exponent"
b#a=t$a^b
0!a=e"Division by zero"
b!a|mod a b>0=e"Uneven division"
b!a=t$div a b
t 13=e"13 is bad luck!"
t x|x<0=e"Integer underflow"|x>99=e"Integer overflow"|1<2=Right x
f(x:y)=foldl(>>=)(t x)$zipWith id(cycle[q(+),q(-),(#),(!),q(*)])y
q=((t.).).flip
```

This wraps the error handling in the `Either e` monad, i.e. the result is either `Left <ErrorMsg>` or `Right <Number>`, for example:

```
*Main> f [6,6,10,6,8,7,9,56,2,9,11]
Right 99
*Main> f [6,6,10,6,8,7,9,56,2,0,8] 
Left "Division by zero"
```

How it works: define custom versions for operators with individual error handling, i.e. `#` for `^` and `!` for `/` (resp. `div` as it is called in Haskell) and lift the others (`+`, `-`, `*`) via `q` into the monad. The main function `f` creates a list of unary function form the numbers (without the first one) and the list of the operators in order, e.g. `[+6, -10, #6, !8, ...]` and reduces this list by feeding the first number into a chain of `>>=`.

Edit: @Angs found a bug. Fixing it saved 4 bytes.

Comment: Since yours is the only only answer yet, how would you feel about retroactively adding a clause that any exceptions must be caught at some point – I think it would better demonstrate error handling capabilities

Comment: Allright, done.

Comment: One problem I think, inputs aren't checked to be 13, only outputs.

Comment: @Angs: Yes, but luckily it's easy to fix. It even saved 4 bytes. Thanks!